# How does require() in node.js work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, require, apply

I tried this:

```
// mod.js
var a = 1;
this.b = 2;
exports.c = 3;

// test.js
var mod = require('./mod.js');
console.log(mod.a);    // undefined
console.log(mod.b);    // 2
console.log(mod.c);    // 3, so this === exports?
```

So I image that require() may be implement like this:

```
var require = function (file) {
    var exports = {};
    var run = function (file) {
        // include "file" here and run
    };
    run.apply(exports, [file]);
    return exports;
}
```

Is that right? Please help me to understand require(), or where can I find the source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Source code is [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354). `exports`/`require` are not keywords, but global variables. Your main script is [wrapped](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/6cbfcdad46d733bb04332063727e304e449dc86b/src/node.js#L780) before [start](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/6cbfcdad46d733bb04332063727e304e449dc86b/src/node.js#L794) in a function which has all the globals like `require`, `process` etc in its context.

Note that while module.js itself is using `require()`, that's a different require function, and it is [defined](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/src/node.js#L861-L949) in the file called "node.js"

Side effect of above: it's perfectly fine to have "return" statement in the middle of your module (not belonging to any function), effectively "commenting out" rest of the code

Comment: This doesn'y make it any simplier. That module uses `require` while it also defines `require`. That's a move I find a little bit hard to understand given that source code only.

Comment: require in the module itself is a different [require](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/src/node.js#L871). Simplified version of Module is created to bootstrap module system - look at the code here - https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/src/node.js#L861-L949

Comment: Where is the documentation for these global variable and its return value?

Comment: @Srikan in official docs - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper  ( I'm not exactly correct about calling exports/require global variables - usually they are the arguments to a wrapper function which is called when your module is loaded  )

Comment: require is not a global variable tmk, it's bound to current file's __dirpath, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderMills it's not exactly global variable, it's coming from the fact that every module is wrapped inside a function and `require` is passed as one of the arguments to that function

Answer (score 13):

```
var mod = require('./mod.js');
```

The require is a function that takes one argument called path, in this case the path is `./mod.js`

when the require is invoked, a sequences of tasks are happened:

1. call `Module.prototype.require` function declared in [lib/module.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js) which assert that the path exists and was a string
2. call `Module._load` which is a function in [lib/module.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js) that resolve the file through `Module._resolveFilename(request, parent, isMain)`,
3. the `Module._resolveFilename` function is called and checks if the module is native (The native modules are returned by `NativeModule` function defined in [lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js)),
   if yes it will return the module else it checks  the number of characters of the parh (Must 2 character at least) and some characters (the path must started by ***`./`***) 
   via `Module._resolveLookupPaths` function defined in defined in [lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js)
4. check the directory that contains the file
5. If the path contains an extension (in our example yes: mod.js), the basename function defined in [lib/path.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js) checks that the extension is "**js**"
6. then it will create a new module for the file given in argument `var module = new Module(filename, parent);`
7. the content will be compiled via v8 through the function `NativeModule.prototype.compile` defined in [lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js)
8. the `NativeModule.wrap` defined in [lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js) takes the javascript content compiled of `mod.js` and wraps it : It wraps it in some other code that makes all this work.
   So the code you've written in `mod.js` is wrapped in a function expression. that means everything you write in node is run in V8
9. a module.exports is what's returned

Answer (score 9):

[Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705115/andrey-sidorov) showed the source code, but if you also wonder how to use it, the easy and simple explanation is here (http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

These were two good examples for me.

```
//foo.js, multiple methods
var circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log( 'The area of a circle of radius 4 is ' + circle.area(4));

//circle.js
var PI = Math.PI;
exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};
exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};

//bar.js
var square = require('./square.js');
var mySquare = square(2);
console.log('The area of my square is ' + mySquare.area());

//square.js, single method
module.exports = function(width) {
  return {
    area: function() {
      return width * width;
    }
  };
}
```

My favourite pattern is

```
(function (controller) {

  controller.init = function (app) {

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
        res.render("index", {});
    });

  };
})(module.exports);
```

Comment: If define a `var express = require('express')`, why after it, they have to redefine another variable as `var app = express()` ?

Comment: didn't get how is your favourite pattern related to require

Comment: @TomSawyer, because `require('express')` return a function that return an app. It's just the way they built it. Hopefully since you asked that question 4 years ago you already answered it.

Answer (score 2):

I dig a little more of nodejs source code/2/ and make a sequence diagram/1/, hope this could give you a intuitive overview. There is another article http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/ which also explain the require() mechanism in a easy way, go through this article first could help you to understand the diagram quickly.
[image]

Ref:

/1/ diagram source repo: https://github.com/z1yuan/nodejs.git

/2/ https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive.git

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
This is a snippet of what I used to create the same functionality as Node.js

```js
/*
FILE: require.js
*/
/*
This is the file used
*/
window.require = function(src, ret) {
  if (src === 'jsmediatags') {
    src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsmediatags/3.9.5/jsmediatags.js';
  };
  var d = document.createElement('script');
  d.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(d);
  var fullURL = src.split('://');
  var neededURL = fullURL[1];
  var nameParts = neededURL.split('/');
  var nameNUM = nameParts.length - 1;
  var fileName = nameParts[nameNUM];
  var g = fileName.split('.');
  var global = g[0];
  if (ret === true) {
    return window[global]
  };
};
```

See if this works, and to add more files to its library, just type more in. (if (src===yourfilenamehere) { src = "path/to/your/file" }

Comment: This doesn't answer what the OP was asking. The OP asked how the `require` function works and how it can be implemented. This solution is how to recreate the `node.js` `require` function with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The module loading mechanism in Node.js is caching the modules on the first `require` call. It means that every time you use `require('xyz-module')` you will get the same instance of `xyz-module`, which ensures that the modules are singleton-like and have the same state across your application.

You can load **`native modules`** and path references from your file system or installed modules. If the identifier passed to the `require` function is not a native module or a file reference (beginning with `/, ../, ./ or similar`), then Node.js will look for installed modules. It will walk your file system looking for the referenced module in the node_modules folder. It starts from the parent directory of your current module and then moves to the parent directory until it finds the right module or until the root of the file system is reached.

Answer (score -10):

The source is available here next to the downloads : http://nodejs.org/ exports/require are keywords, I don't think they are coded in javascript directly. Node is coded in C++ , javascript is just a scripting shell around the C++ core.

Comment: when you just "think" or guess, it's better don't answer questions. When a module is loaded and parsed from filesystem, it's wrapped in a function  and them compiled by the v8 engine, and finally the module is cached. `require`, `module`, `__filename`, etc are functions and variables injected into the module after compilation, and the module runs in the v8 engine context, but the module itself is a closure, so variables and functions are never conflicted ( except in the case you use the global variable and mess.