# what does var io = require('../..')(server) do?

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs, socket.io-1.0

I've build the project https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat locally and it is working great.  However, it would be nice to understand a little more about how a socket application works.

In the main startup script one of the modules that is pulled in with require is

```
var io = require('../..')(server)
```

what does require('../..') do?

thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475792/how-does-require-in-node-js-work) has a few links to resources about require.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a path to a directory is given to `require`, it will implicitly look for an `index.js` in that directory.

In this case, it's the equivalent of

```
var socket = require("../../index.js");
var io     = socket(server);
```

In the example provided, they're just using some shorthand and throw away the intermediate value returned by the call to `require`.

Check out the [module.require docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) for more info.

Comment: i dont understand why we are requiring index.js. we are inside index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in your code

> require('../..');

Will add File form the path, which have used SOCKET.IO, as you can see that you have not added Socket.io module.

Also, if no specific path give for file or folder, Module require will try to load **index.js** or **index.node**. if no such file exist then it will give error.