# Require method in javascript

Tags: javascript, ng-admin

I'm not an expert with javascript.

I'm wondering, from which library you get the `require` method

For example, in main.js : (https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin-demo/blob/master/js/main.js)

```
require('./customers/config')(nga, admin);
```

Thank you !

Comment: RequireJS is one. I don't know if Angular supplies it itself. You'll also see it in NodeJS code; in that instance, it's provided by Node.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to support modules in the **browser**:
AMD, CommonJS, UMD and RequireJS(browser only). In your particular example, I think webpack will pack all the modules together(see dev dependecies in that project and [webpack config in the project](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin-demo/blob/master/webpack.config.js)).
See:

1. https://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html
2. [How to require CommonJS modules in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576001/how-to-require-commonjs-modules-in-the-browser)
3. https://pixelsvsbytes.com/2013/02/js-require-for-browsers-better-faster-stronger/
4. https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

In the **NodeJS** require is a global function:
See: 
[How does require() in node.js work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475792/how-does-require-in-node-js-work)